# Efficient pointer to integer mapping and lookup in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I want to map pointer to integer for purpose of serialization. The pointers may be of different types and may point to polymorphic objects possibly using multiple inheritance. I need to query the map to know if the pointer is stored in it and if it is, then what is the associated integral value.

What is the correct way to do it?

The simple way of `map<void*, int>` that I thought of would not work because `operator <` is not defined for arbitrary pointers. Or is that not a problem on common systems?

Another solution would be to have a `vector<void*>`. But this would require to loop over all pointers stored in and I am not sure if the casting to `void *` would not break the `operator ==` for objects using inheritance.

Comment: "that I thought of would not work because operator < is not defined for arbitrary pointers." - The standard says that the behavior is unspecified. So it will definitely work unless the order of storage of those pointers is important (which I doubt)

Comment: Have you considered using a library? Examples: s11.net or boost.serialization

Comment: Yes I considered using boost::serialization, but it would require some tweaking to be usable on my data.

Comment: If you want efficiency you can look at boost::unordored_map I think it should be better but I didn't look at it yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in luck with your initial idea of using `map<void*, int>`.
Although you are right that `operator<` is not defined for pointers, the predicate used by `std::map<>` is `std::less<>` and the C++ standard requires that `std::less<T*>` also works for arbitrary pointers.

Quote from the C++ standard to support this ([lib.comparisons]/8):

> For templates `greater`, `less`, `greater_equal`, and `less_equal`, the specializations for any pointer type yield a total order, even if the built-in operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` do not.

Comment: I doubt this: Any reference for this

Comment: Updated my answer with a supporting quote.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply introduce a dummy base class for all of your serializable classes ?

```
class Serializable
{
};

map< Serializable *, int > integralMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just do a map of unsigned int32/64 to int (depending on x86 or x64). Just cast the void* to the unsigned int and it'll happily do the comparison.

Comment: Ok, I may cast the pointer to size_t to be sure it fits, but will that not alter the equality of pointers when using inheritance?

Comment: It is not so good idea to do this. It looks more like a hack!. If you follow this, make sure you document it so well!.

Comment: please use at least intptr_t or uintptr_t, these are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computing)#C_and_C.2B.2B
- http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html